# srcdoc attribute of iframes as a source of XSS attacks

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, xss

I am trying to implement a case where a user provides us some html code which is then stored in our database. We then retrieve the HTML from our database as a string. (We have no control over the user input)

I try to embed this html using

```
const htmldoc = [the raw html]
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" srcdoc=htmldoc>
</iframe>
```

I would be using a data:// URI. Or blob:// URI.

I am using the sandbox attribute to prevent Same Origin Policy. Can a user input something which might lead to XSS attacks in the parent browsing context? I am not concerned if the XSS attack targets the content inside the iframe since it is sandboxed.

If my approach is vulnerable to attacks, what can I do to make it secure?

Comment: It's not XSS but one thing a malicious user might try is embedding malware either directly or through a link, include, redirect.

Comment: Since I have sandboxed the iframe (only scripts are allowed to run but they can't interact with the parent DOM or cookies or local storage), so it shouldn't be harmful for my actual website, right?

Comment: Probably not, though I think there have been some 0-day exploits that escaped sandboxing.  Either way, allowing people to infect visitors' computers is not good.  "(We have no control over the user input)" is not safe.